# Can I configure pull-before-restart in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have `docker-compose.yml` file with container which automatically crashes when it gets outdated. I would love to set automatic pulling when the container restarts on it's own. Is this supported in by docker-compose out of the box?

Edit: Let me be more specific.

Container is running long time, update is released during that time. Container crashes. Policy is restart-always, therefore compose will restart container automatically. I need pull before that restart.

I know how to do it in bash,but was hoping compose supports it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't have docker-compose re-pull an image when spawned containers from it fail for some reason. You're only left to work with [pull_policy](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#pull_policy) which alas instructs docker compose to always pull prior to building/launching a container. You'll need to automate the pull-on-failure feature with some scripting around compose.